# Invalid Number with date filter in Oracle SQL where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, date, where-clause

Using Oracle SQL, I am getting this error with my query:

ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

I am using two tables to get a maximum date and min date from a transaction table for requests. Without the line "AND mgr_min.create_date > to_date('01-01-15', 'MM-DD-YY')" it seems to return the results I need. But when I try to filter based on date that a request was created...I get the error. Here is the query:

```
SELECT mr.accessor_id,
   mrs.status_description,
   mso.option_name,
   CAST(mgr_max.create_date AS TIMESTAMP) AS "Action Date",
   mgr_max.detail_comment AS "Comment",
   mgr_min.create_date AS "Date Created"
FROM moca_request mr,
   moca_request_status mrs,
   moca_system_option mso,
   moca_system ms,
 (SELECT mrt.request_id, mrt.status_id, mrt.approver_id, mrt.create_date, mrt.detail_comment
  FROM moca_request_transaction mrt
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT request_id, MAX(create_date) AS maxdate
    FROM moca_request_transaction
    GROUP BY request_id) mrt2
    ON mrt.request_id = mrt2.request_id AND mrt.create_date = mrt2.maxdate) mgr_max,
  (SELECT mrt3.create_date, mrt3.request_id
   FROM moca_request_transaction mrt3
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT request_id, MIN(create_date) AS createdate
    FROM moca_request_transaction
    GROUP BY request_id) mrt4
    ON mrt3.request_id = mrt4.request_id AND mrt3.create_date = mrt4.createdate) mgr_min      
WHERE mgr_max.request_id = mr.request_id
AND   mgr_max.status_id = mrs.status_id
AND   mgr_min.request_id = mr.request_id
AND   mso.option_id = mr.option_id
AND   ms.system_id = mr.system_id
AND   mgr_min.create_date > to_date('01-01-15', 'MM-DD-YY')
```

Comment: can you ensure that create_date is of date type ? maybe it is varchar or number

Comment: the create_date in moca_request_transaction has the data type of date...Is there a way to tell if it was converted? could it be converted?

Comment: Without the filter is it returning all the records, are are you getting a few and then stopping the output, or only seeing the first page in the data grid? It's possible another field - presumably from one of your old-style joins - is a `varchar2` containing some non-numbers; with the date filter you're hitting that earlier. It would be interesting to make sure you have pulled all records without the date check, to see if the error pops up at some point.